# Does locally a summand imply summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have an $R$-module $M$ with $R$ an integral domain. The localizatiom $(tM)_P$ of the torsion submodule of $M$ is a summand of $M_P$ for each maximal ideal $P.$ Does it follow that $tM$ is a summand of $M?$ Part of me wants to say yes, but part of me says maybe not.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.